# How are users on an application running in a container split over the ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, cloud, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

So I want to launch a web application, and run it on containers in AWS.
I want to give users access to the tool through a log in page.

I don't understand how AWS manages the relationship of containers and the instances backing them.

My main questions are -

1. Will multiple containers run on a single ec2 instance?
2. If the compute power required by a container exceeds the processing power of a single instance, and I have auto-scaling enabled, will it launch multiple instances to support a single container? or will I need to go in and upgrade my ec2 instance type?
3. Finally, when users log in to the app, will AWS deploy a new container for each user, and subsequently a new instance to run on? or can one container support multiple users?

Also a link to a page where I can find this information would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: Read https://aws.amazon.com/containers/ & then read relevant ECS or Fargate documentation (depending on if you want managed serverless containers or not) - all your questions will be answered in the docs :)

Answer (score -1):

I will try to answer your questions, but how @Ermiya Eskandary said, the documentation will answer all the questions about container in AWS.

1. Yes, if your have for example a 2gb memory and 1vcpu ec2 instance and your container need a 500mb memory and 0,25vcpu, you can run a lot of containers inside EC2. You can set the task placement group to tell AWS how to handle container into EC2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement.html
2. No, if your container size exceeds your ec2 instance, is impossible to share the resources of multiple ec2 to hold on one single container. If you are using ecs core (ec2 mode), the ec2 size always need to be bigger than the container.
3. No, you will use one container to attend multiple clients, if you are running out resources, your ASG will increase number of tasks running, using the rule that i said in the first point.

To finish, based on my experience, if your use case don't need to work with cores of machine, using a custom AMI or any other thing in the infrastructure level (linux/windows), i would use ec2 fargate.
Fargate have less operational overhead, since you need to orchestrate auto scalling group both in ec2 and in your tasks using ecs with ec2.

Comment: My company is launching an ML application, so we may need to launch on ec2 backed. Do you know if its possible to do reserved pricing with fargate?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: When you reserve an instance, you get billed for all possible hours of use for the reservation period at the beginning of the period, whether you use the hours or not.